# How to validate variables contents in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

ansible-lint only checks the tasks/handlers and doesn't iterate over the variables (e.g. if you're using `with_items`, it won't iterate over all the items) and yamllint only checks cosmetic issues and is hard to customized with custom rules.

Is there a tool that can validate the actual data in the variables in YAML files before they are fed into Ansible?

Examples:

- A given variable cannot contain a specific string
- Variable `user_ssh_key` fed to `authorized_keys` cannot have a comment
- Variable `ssh_enabled` fed to `service` module cannot be True
- and so on...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [assert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) and [testing-strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) to achieve that.

Like so:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    variable: 'green'
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: variable is match("green")
        success_msg: "Variable is green"
        fail_msg: "Variable is not green"
```

You can

> match strings against a substring or a regular expression, use the `match`, `search` or `regex` tests

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks, that is a valid concern. Fixed it and used a non boolean in the example